# Remove repeating character

Tags: php, regex

How would I remove repeating characters (e.g. remove the letter `k` in `cakkkke` for it to be `cake`)?

One straightforward way to do this would be to loop through each character of the string and append each character of the string to a new string if the character isn't a repeat of the previous character.

Here is some code that can do this:

```
$newString = '';
$oldString = 'cakkkke';
$lastCharacter = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($oldString); $i++) {
    if ($oldString[$i] !== $lastCharacter) {
        $newString .= $oldString[$i];
    }
    $lastCharacter = $oldString[$i];
}
echo $newString;
```

Is there a way to do the same thing more concisely using regex or built-in functions?

Comment: what would you expect on words like `look,free,tree`?

Comment: @Lawrence Cherone : i would want it to replace only if the character occurs more than n number of times. I would typically set the n value to be 4 or higher

Comment: @Lawrence Cherone - yes I can play with the value to see what suits best.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Use backrefrences

```
echo preg_replace("/(.)\\1+/", "$1", "cakkke");
```

Output:

```
cake
```

Explanation:

`(.)` captures any character

`\\1` is a backreferences to the first capture group. The `.` above in this case.

`+` makes the backreference match atleast 1 (so that it matches aa, aaa, aaaa, but not a)

Replacing it with `$1` replaces the complete matched text `kkk` in this case, with the first capture group, `k` in this case.

Comment: nice it works, can you help further by explaining the regex. I dont understand how it works: the slashes? the 1? the +?

Comment: @Imran, check my updated answer. If anything is still unclear, feel free to ask.

Comment: how could I change to to only replace if the character occurs more than n number of times?

Comment: Please note this regex does not take international characters into consideration.

Comment: See a very interesting variant of this answer in this link: https://randomdrake.com/2008/04/10/php-and-regex-replacing-repeating-characters-with-single-characters-in-a-string/. It's preg_replace('{(.)\1+}', ...). Do you see it: there's no two slashes enclose the pattern string.

Answer (score 1):

You want to first match a character, followed by that character repeated: `(.)\1+`. Replace that with the first character. The [brackets](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) create a backreference to the first character, which you use both to match the repeated instances and as the replacement text.

```
preg_replace('/(.)\1+/', '$1', $str);
```