# delete the repetetion letters in a string php

Tags: php, string

I'm trying to parse a string and delete the adjacent letters that are same. I want to return the count of number of deletions and output the resulted string after the deletions are made. Say I have

```
$str = "aaabbbcc";
```

As you can see, you need to do 5 deletions to make the adjacent letters not same. The `$output` string is `"abc"` and the number of deletions is `five`.

```
function str_deletions ($str)
{
    $prev = $str[0];
    $length = strlen($str);
    $deletions = 0;
    $output = "";

    for ($i=1 ; $i < $length; $i++)
    {
        if ($str[$i]== $prev)
        {
            $deletions++;
            $prev = $str[$i];  // not sure here ?
        }
    }
    echo $output;   // ? 
    return $deletions;
}
$str = "aabbcc";
echo str_deletions ($str);
```

**EDIT**
This is an interview question, I'm not supposed to use any built-in functions like `regex or array_count_values`
Thanks for your help !

Comment: Yes, a regex would be simpler. Possible duplicate of [Remove repeating character](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6723389)

Comment: @mario I want to count the number of deletions as well..

Comment: `preg_replace('/[a-z]+/', '$1', $str);` or something like that. amount of deletions: `strlen($str)-strlen($result)`. *not tested*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic algorithm (indeed `$prev = $str[$i];` isn't at the good place but you wasn't far):

```
function str_deletion($str) {
    $del = 0;
    if (1 < $length = strlen($str)) { // $str has more than 1 char
        $prev = $str[0];
        $output = $prev;

        for ($i=1; $i<$length; $i++) {
            if ($prev == $str[$i]) {
                $del++;
            } else {
                $prev = $str[$i]; // when different, change the previous character
                $output .= $prev; // and append it to the output
            }
        }
    } else {
        $output = $str;
    }
    echo $output;
    return $del;
}
```

Comment: @WildWidow if you feel that Casimir has answered your question, or anyone else, please do mark it as correct so future users can find this question and what worked for you. Also it stops it going into the humungous pile of "unanswered questions that actually have answers" ;). Good luck with the job.

Comment: Don't worry about it - we don't care about being accepted, we all provided different solutions. Glad you're sorted though.

Answer (score 2):

### Regex solution

This is a much simpler way of doing what you're after using `preg_replace()`:

```
<?php
    function str_deletions($str){
        $replaced = preg_replace("/(.)\\1+/", "", $str);
        $length = strlen($str) - strlen($replaced);
        return array("new_word" => $replaced, "chars_replaced" => $length);
    }

    $str = "aabbcc";
    $string_deletions = str_deletions($str);
    echo "New String: " . $string_deletions['new_word'] . "\n";
    echo "Chars deleted: " . $string_deletions['chars_replaced'] . "\n";
?>
```

### No inbuilt functions

For the purposes of completion (and since you updated your question with more information to say that we can't use regexes because it's an interview question), here's what I'd do:

**Using `count_chars()`**:

```
function str_deletions($str){
    $string_data['new_word'] = count_chars($str,3);
    $string_data['chars_replaced'] = strlen($str) - strlen($string_data['new_word']);
    return $string_data;
}

$str = "aabbcc";
echo str_deletions($str);
```

**Note:** in this example `count_chars();` will return **unique** chars in a string, not quite remove duplicates (i.e. "aabbccaa" would still yield "abc" as an output) but your question wasn't clear what the interviewer wanted - whether it *was* truly a remove duplicate question or a unique char question.

**Using `array_unique()`:**

Slightly slower and a bit more heavy handed:

```
function str_deletions($str){
    $string_array = array_unique(str_split($str));
    foreach($string_array as $string_cur){
        $string_data['new_word'] .= $string_cur;
    }
    $string_data['chars_replaced'] = strlen($str) - strlen($string_data['new_word']);
    return $string_data;
}

$str = "aabbcc";
echo str_deletions($str);
```

**Note:** It's worth pointing out that if I realised it was an interview question, I wouldn't have provided an answer as doing it *for* you kind of defeats the purpose.  Still, with the amount of answers here now and the fact that I've seen something similar to this in an interview, my hope is someone will learn from these.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another regex solution. I use a regex to only match a word character that is repeated, and then remove each consecutive repeating character one by one, which allows me to use `&$count` argument with [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

> **count**
>   If specified, this variable will be filled with the number of replacements done.

The regex is

```
(\w)(?=\1)
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/rG4pN8/2). Note you can replace `\w` with `.` to match any character but a newline. OR if you need to match only letters, I suggest using `'/(\p{L})(?=\1)/u'`

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/sANCkO):

```
$str = "aaabbbcc"; 
$cnt = -1;
$result = preg_replace('/(\w)(?=\1)/', "", $str, -1, $cnt);
echo "Result: " . $result . PHP_EOL . "Deletions: " . $cnt;
```

Output:

```
Result: abc
Deletions: 5
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it works, Wondering if we can do this the old fashioned way without regex :)

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I don't like regex. its confusing :(

Comment: @WildWidow: I understand regex may be confusing, but in this case, it is rather straight-forward: `(\w)` matches and captures a word character into group 1 and while there is the same character after it (`(?=\1)`), delete it and save deletion count into `$count` with `preg_replace`. You added the no-regex-please restriction later. I still hope this answer will be useful for someone if not you.

Comment: @stribizhev Thank you, upped your post.

Comment: @WildWidow Not understanding regex in this case has caused you to write umpteen extra lines of code. If you add that up over the course of a year with all the times you could have written a regex to do something quicker and simpler I think you'll find it was worth learning! Start slow, with something like [regexr](http://regexr.com).

Comment: Just noticed the edit to your question saying this is an interview question and regexes aren't allowed...

Answer (score 1):

Solved with no external function except count;

```
$str="aaavvvffccca";
$count = strlen($str);
 for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
      $array[]=$str[$i];
    }
$del   =0;
    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
      $next=isset($array[$i+1])?$array[$i+1]:null;
      if($array[$i]==$next)
      {
              $del++;
      }
      else
      {
        $newarray[]=$array[$i];
      }

    }

echo "Filter Text:". implode('',$newarray);
echo"Total Deleted:".$del;
```

Comment: count_chars won't work in this case, say if the input string is "aaabbbcca"  I want the output to be "abca".

Answer (score 1):

I have changed your function
this is not returning both the output string and number of deletions

```
            function str_deletions ($str)
            {
                $prev = NULL;
                $deletions = 0;
                $output = "";
                $i=0;
                while ($i < strlen($str))
                {
                    if (substr($str,$i,1) == $prev)
                    {
                        $deletions++;
                        //$prev = substr($str,$i,1);/*remove this line, no need here as the same stmnt is there after ifelse*/
                    }else{
                        $output.=substr($str,$i,1);
                    }
                    $prev = substr($str,$i,1);
                    $i++;
                }
                $arr = array(
                    'output'=>$output,
                    'deletions'=>$deletions
                );
                return $arr;
            }
            $str = "aaabbcc";
            print_r(str_deletions ($str));
```

output for above function call is

```
Array ( [output] => abc [deletions] => 4 )
```

Comment: I have edited the question to comment extra line, also remove in your code

Answer (score 0):

The straight forward solution to find out the number of deletions can be

```
If there are N consecutive same characters delete N-1 out of those N characters.

function str_likes($str)
{
    $length = strlen($str);
    $del = 0;
    for ($i=0 ; $i < $length ; $i++)
    {
        if ($str[$i] == $str[$i+1])
        {
            $del++;
        }
    }
    return $del;
}
$str = "aabbccaaa";
echo str_likes($str); //4
```