# PHP inside foreach issue

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have this foreach :

```
  <?php foreach ($manufacturers as $key => $manufacturer) {


        if($manufacturer->virtuemart_manufacturercategories_id == 1){
            $lang = 'heb'; //Hebrew
        } else {
            $lang = 'eng'; //English
        }

        //add to letter list


         $letter = mb_substr($manufacturer->mf_name, 0, 1, 'UTF-8');
         ${'html_letters_'.$lang}[] = $letter;

      /*
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($manufacturer);
        echo '</pre>';*/

        $link = JROUTE::_('index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=category&virtuemart_manufacturer_id=' . $manufacturer->virtuemart_manufacturer_id);

        ${'html_manufacturers_'.$lang} .= '<div class="manufacturer" data-lang="'.$lang.'" data-letter="'.$letter.'"><a href="'.$link.'">';
        ?>
        <?php
        if ($manufacturer->images && ($show == 'image' or $show == 'all' )) {
            ${'html_manufacturers_'.$lang} .= $manufacturer->images[0]->displayMediaThumb('',false);
        }
        if ($show == 'text' or $show == 'all' ) {
            ${'html_manufacturers_'.$lang} .= '<div>'.$manufacturer->mf_name.'</div>';
        }
            ${'html_manufacturers_'.$lang} .= '</a>
        </div> <!-- /manufacturer -->';

        if ($col == $manufacturers_per_row){
            $col = 1;
        } else {
            $col++;
        }
    } 



    ?>
```

How i check if i have more then 2 same letters and unset all others but keep one.

The output for letter is :

```
AABCHKIUKP
```

I want this will be :

```
ABCHKIUKP
```

How i do this ?

EDIT: I have updated all the foreach code. The issue is if i have more then same start letter in name EG:Aroma,Air the loop the take the first letter A and foreach him 2 times, i want to show only one if there even 10 same start letter in name .

Thanks.

Comment: I cannot add comments, so my post was converted to comment (thanks stackoverflow :) ). The solution is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6723389/remove-repeating-character

Comment: I already tried that. how over its not working for mb( utf-8 ) chars . Also here its inside foreach, so $letter return each time the first letter of name

Answer (score 0):

When I understand you right ... just use an array

```
<?php 
      $letters = array();
      foreach ($manufacturers as $key => $manufacturer) {
           ....
           $letter = mb_substr($manufacturer->mf_name, 0, 1, 'UTF-8');
           $letters[] = $letter;
      }
      $uni = array_unique($letters)
      echo implode('',$uni);
```

Comment: Okay,of cours that would work,how i do it inside the foreach and not outside the foreach ?

Comment: I tried to combine this with mine not working like i want.

Answer (score 0):

```
$s = 'AABCHKIUKP';

$letters = $letters = preg_split('/(?<!^)(?!$)/u', $s); //utf8
$prev_letter = '';
$temp = '';
foreach($letters as $key => $letter) {
    if (!($letter === $prev_letter)) {
        $temp .= $letter;
    }
    $prev_letter = $letter;
}
echo $temp;
```

Result:

> ABCHKIUKP

Info about breaking a utf8 string to an array you can find at comments here [mb_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-split.php).

Answer (score 0):

To strip **ONLY same consecutive** chars you can use this:

```
function stripConsecutiveChars( $string ) {
    // creates an array with chars from the string
    $charArray = str_split( $string );

    // saves the last char thats on the new string
    $lastChar = "";

    // variable for the new string to return
    $returnString = "";

    foreach( $charArray as $char ) {
        if( $char === $lastChar ) continue;

        $lastChar = $char;// save current char
        $returnString .= $char;// concat current char to new string
    }

    return $returnString;
}

$string = "AABCHKIUKP";
echo stripConsecutiveChars( $string );
```

**In your example you could try this:**

```
...
$letter = mb_substr( $manufacturer->mf_name, 0, 1, 'UTF-8' );
$lastLetter = end( ${'html_letters_' . $lang} );//point to last element in array
reset( ${'html_letters_' . $lang} );// reset the pointer
if( $letter === $lastLetter ) {
    // i guess you just want to continue?
    continue;
}
...
```

OUTPUT:

> ABCHKIUKP

Comment: Not working inside my foreach. take a look more close, i take a name for the foreach take hte first letter and then use this to print a list.

Comment: well you can put the function somewhere but not directly into your foreach, where comes `AABCHKIUKP` from? Is it in your `$manufacturer->mf_name`? And do you want to strip only the first char?

Comment: I've updated my answer, If this is not working you have to update your question and add some more information about it, were comes the string from, and where is the output,....

Comment: after you updated your question, I just updated my answer **again** :)